# Cannot select more than 1 email when invoking our Outlook Add-In

Tags: outlook, office-js

We just released our Office JS Add-In for Outlook. Our Add-In takes one or more emails and sends them to an external web service to upload as a case note attachment for our enterprise application. With the previous Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) technology, we could invoke our Add-In with any number of emails selected so that many could be sent at one time. With the Office JS technology, if we select any more than 1 email, the Add-In button is not enabled and we can't invoke our Add-In. We have 12,000 customers using this tool using VSTO and they will report this as a bug for our Add-In given that the old technology works and the new technology does not. We would like this capability added for Office JS so our customers can do what they did using VSTO.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature request on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page.
It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the existing request https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/11080962-allow-outlook-add-in-commands-to-be-used-on-select. Feature request on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Our primary concern is that our users were able to select multiple emails with the previous VSTO add-in and this will appear as a bug to them with the Office JS add-in not allowing this. We would hope that this feature would be prioritized high since appears as a bug and is a feature that was possible with the previous VSTO technology.